How to run snakemake on AWS now that Tibanna is not anymore available on Snakemake 8
Currently I am running snakemake pipelines on AWS using an older version of Snakemake (7.30.0). I would like to update to a more recent version of Snakemake. Unfortunately it seems that Tibanna is not supported anymore on Snakemake 8.
What would be the best way to run a Snakemake pipeline on AWS using Snakemake 8? Using Kubernetes? And is there a tutorial that describes how to do this?

I was able to run Snakemake 8 pipelines on AWS using k8s and I've also seen an AWS batch plugin but I haven't tested it. I am also interested to hear if anyone has any experience with this.
